# ocaml top: getting user's input

Tags: ocaml, typerex

Could you please show me how to get user's input in Ocaml-top?

It can be found in this link: http://www.typerex.org/ocaml-top.html

I'm a beginner in Ocaml and I'm trying to get the user's input to run [this example](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/oreilly-book/html/book-ora027.html)

This is the code:

```
let rec hilo n =
     let () = print_string "type a number: " in
     let i = read_int () 
     in 
       if i = n then 
         let () = print_string "BRAVO" in
         let () = print_newline ()
         in print_newline ()
       else 
         let () = 
           if i < n then 
             let () = print_string "Higher"
             in print_newline () 
           else 
             let () = print_string "Lower"
             in print_newline ()
         in hilo n ;;
```

But the program stop at `Type a number`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really possible. OCaml-top sends its commands to the ocaml interpreter through the standard input, and read_int reads inputs on stdin also. This problem is tracked at https://github.com/OCamlPro/ocaml-top/issues/45

Comment: Then there is no way to get the user's input ... This means I will need to run from command line. Oh dear ...

Comment: Where is the problem? In the toplevel, just type in `let i = ...` and remove the `i` declaration line in this code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run it from command prompt.
Type this command in the command prompt: ocaml filename.ml
You can use it only if you have set the path in environment variables.

Comment: i have tried this but i still cant get the user input! Any idea ??

Answer (score 0):

I have this working and the diff with the file above is zero

```
$ ocaml
```

starts the interpreter

```
# #directory "/home/wherever-your-OCaml-stuff-is";;
```

yes, type the extra # and the ;;

```
# #use "hilo.ml";;
```

no need to compile anything

```
# hilo 24356256456;;
```

it is not much of a guessing game...